# Whatsapp Web Selenium with C# send message without reloads the web page every time

Tags: c#, selenium, whatsapp

I have created one project for automating Whatsapp message using web Whatsapp with selenium in C# code. It works perfectly fine but every time the URL is loaded for new message, how can I stop reloading the page and send message?

Below is my code and I have one for `loop` for all my numbers and I am calling `SendMessage` method for every numbers.

```
private void SendMessage(string number, string message)
{
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); 

  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number + "&text=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(message));

  driver.FindElement(By.Id("action-button")).Click(); 

  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button._2lkdt>span")).Click();
}
```

Comment: driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number + "&text=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(message)); your write this in loop because of that it will load url every time

Comment: Hi @Dhru'soni is There any way going to net contact without loading page again?
 Because in NAvigate().Goto() load the Whatsapp Web everytime.. how to go to  **"send?phone="** with new phone number.

Comment: Have you found the way out of this issue? please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get search box
var SearchBox = WebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='side']/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p")).SingleOrDefault();
if (SearchBox != null)
{
    // Click and type the mobile number, then press the enter key
    SearchBox.Click();
    SearchBox.SendKeys("MobileNumber");
    SearchBox.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

    // Get message box
    var MessageBox = WebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p")).SingleOrDefault();
    if (MessageBox != null)
    {
        // Type message to send, and click send button
        MessageBox.SendKeys("TextMessage");
        WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button/span")).Click();
    }
    // Messag sent
}
```

Comment: could you add a few lines of explanation?

Comment: I think a detailed explanation of how this code was created would help this answer withstand the test of time. As the whatsapp website changes over time the bespoke selectors in  this answer will need adjusting. A more generic answer with further discussion would be more valuable.